# How to Fix "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "?

Tags: android

> I am trying to get the text from EditText and passing it as double to this Function
>
> Here is my code :

```
 private MapViewLite mapView;
EditText lat,longs;
Button search;
String getLang,getlong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lat = findViewById(R.id.lat);
    longs = findViewById(R.id.longs);
    search = findViewById(R.id.search);
    // Get a MapViewLite instance from the layout.
    mapView = findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getLang = lat.getText().toString();
    getlong = longs.getText().toString();
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            loadMapScene(getLang,getlong);
        }
    });
}
private void loadMapScene(String a,String b) {
    // Load a scene from the SDK to render the map with a map style.
    mapView.getMapScene().loadScene(MapStyle.NORMAL_DAY, new LoadSceneCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadScene(@Nullable SceneError sceneError) {
            if (sceneError == null) {
                try {
                    double aa = new Double(getLang);
                    double bb = new Double(getlong);

                    mapView.getCamera().setTarget(new GeoCoordinates(aa, bb));
                    mapView.getCamera().setZoomLevel(14);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Catch :", e.getMessage());
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ERROR ->>> ", "onLoadScene failed: " + sceneError.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

> After i click on the Button i get the Error as :

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
```

> How can this Error be fixed, please reply

Comment: Mark the answer which was helpful to you if any. Users take efforts to answer and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling

```
getLang = lat.getText().toString();
getlong = longs.getText().toString();
```

from `onCreate()`

Those values are not set yes, so its text is "";

Move those into `loadMapScene()` method

Answer (score 0):

```
Add a check for value 
double aa,bb;
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(getLang))
 aa = Double.parseDouble(getLang);
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(getlong))
 bb = Double.parseDouble(getlong);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse your coordinates to double like this

```
double aa = Double.parseDouble(getLang);
double bb = Double.parseDouble(getlong);
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty string is not accepted by double you can do as below

```
double dLang;

try {
    dLang= new Double(getLang);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    dLang = 0; // your default value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in my opinion is:

```
double d;
try {
    d = Double.parseDouble(string);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    d = 0; // or any other default value
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `onCreate()` do this, to get the latitude and longitude when the user clicks search button.

```
search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        getLang = lat.getText().toString();
        getlong = longs.getText().toString();
        loadMapScene(getLang,getlong);
    }
});
```

Inside `loadMapScene()` do this

```
private void loadMapScene(String a,String b) {
    double lat, lng;
    try {
        // Parse the string to double, this will throw exception if
        // parameter a or b contains any trace of string.
        lat = Double.parseDouble(a);
        lng = Double.parseDouble(b);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        // We show a meaning message to user, so that they
        // enter valid location next time.
        toast("Location data invalid");
        // Here we get out of the method without executing any
        // other code in the current method
        return;
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Comment: Hope this helps @EduardoBaitello